# UIButton not responding to touch in UIScrollView nested in another UIScrollView

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uibutton

I have been trying to find a solution to the following problem :
I have a `UIScrollView` (vertical Scroll) in which I have nested another `UIScrollView` (horizontal). Both `UIScrollViews` also have `UIButtons` nested in them. However, the `UIButtons` only respond to touches in the parent `UIScrollView` (vertical).

For some reason, the `UIButtons` in the horizontal (nested) `UIScrollView` don't seem to respond to touch.

I have tried all of the following :

Subclassing both UIScrollViews and overriding the touchesShouldCancelInContentView method like so :

```
override func touchesShouldCancelInContentView(view: UIView) -> Bool {        

   return !view.isKindOfClass(UIButton)

}
```

I also tried to cancel touches for the nested `UIScrollView` from within the parent `UIScrollView` but then I couldn't scroll vertically anymore.

Both my `UIScrollViews` have the following :

```
UISCROLLVIEW.delaysContentTouches = false
UISCROLLVIEW.canCancelContentTouches = true
```

I have tried messing around with these values but never managed to get a touch event on the `UIButton` nested in the nested `UIScrollView`. I have come to a point where I am starting to wonder if this is actually possible… Although it seems like the AppStore is doing it. Or is because they are using `UICollectionViews` ?

Any suggestions ?

**EDIT :** 
I wanted to make sure the touch events WERE being cancelled for the UIScrollView when I was clicking the UIButton, so I logged the touchesBegan of the UIScrollView and sure enough I get a print in the console everywhere in the UIScrollView EXCEPT in when I touch the UIButton. However -and this is strange- if I subclass the UIButton and override touchesBegan I DO NOT get a log ! Really a t a loss…

Comment: Just a reminder, using nested scrollviews isn't the best practise even they scroll in different directions. Beside these problems you might have hard time dealing with content offset and size manually. Try to use collection views or pageviewcontroller inside another scrollview to achieve this. Maybe it helps.

Comment: @Akeara: where did you see that it is not good practice ? I can't see Apple saying this anywhere. On the contrary (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/UIScrollView_pg/NestedScrollViews/NestedScrollViews.html). Moreover, a UICollectionView is nothing else but a UIScrollView subclass.

Answer (score 0):

bring button to front

```
bringSubviewToFront:
```

Comment: Had already tried this. It definitely IS in front. I can actually tell when I click on it as I can get the touchesBegan event on the entire view if I subclass it… except when I click the UIButton

Answer (score 0):

Try it.

```
yourButtonObject.layer.zPosition = 1
```

Comment: Same here. The problem is most probably not related to being able to get access to the UIButton. More related to the touch actions being cancelled on it

Comment: @Sankalap is this intended as an answer to the OP's question?  In which case, can you expand on how your one-liner would provide a solution?